# Why does this pointer to an array expression work

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, implicit-conversion, pointer-arithmetic

I cannot understand why does this code work this way. I know that ptr is a pointer to an array of int and it points to the second “row” of arr.

```
int arr[][2] = { {1}, 2, 3};
int (*ptr)[2] = arr + 1;
printf("%d\n", (**arr)[*ptr]);
```

It prints 3 which is `arr[1][1]` but `**arr` is 1 and `*ptr` is memory address of `arr[1][0]`. 
Why does `(**arr)[*ptr]` return 3? Am I missing something here?

Comment: All of this C-style casting to unrelated types smells like undefined behavior to me.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie What casting?

Comment: `(**arr)` vs. an actual 2-dimensional array.

Comment: There is no casting going on here. `(**arr)` is dereferencing `arr` twice to get `1`. And `arr` is an actual 2-dimensional array.

Comment: ok, there is no casting going on.  Hopefully the OP knows not to cast though, thinking that an `int **` is a 2D array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This declaration

```
int arr[][2] = { {1}, 2, 3};
```

declares an array of two elements of the type `int[2]`.

This expression

```
(**arr)
```

gives the integer value 1.

This declaration

```
int (*ptr)[2] = arr + 1;
```

declares pointer to the second element of the array arr. So *ptr returns this second "row" of the array arr. Using in expressions like this

```
(**arr)[*ptr]
```

it is converted to pointer to its first element.

So you have an expression like

```
int[int *]
```

or

```
i[p]
```

where i is an integer value and p is a pointer.

That is equivalent to

```
int *[int]
```

or

```
p[i]
```

because according to the C++ Standard (or C Standard) the both are evaluated like

```
*( p + i )
```

So as **arr is equal to 1 and the the expression *ptr points to the first element of the second row then the result is the second element of the second row that is 3.

From the C++ 17 Standard (5.2.1 Subscripting)

> 1 A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is
>   a postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type
>   “array of T” or “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped
>   enumeration or integral type. The result is of type “T.” The type “T”
>   shall be a completely-defined object type.64 **The expression E1[E2]
>   is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))** [ Note: see 5.3 and 5.7
>   for details of * and + and 8.3.4 for details of arrays. — end note ],
>   except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue
>   if that operand is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise.

That is if you have an array like this

```
T a[N];
```

where `T` is some type specifier when the expression

```
a[i]
```

is equivalent to

```
i[a]
```

provided that `i` represents a postfix expression.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i != N ) std::cout << i++[a] << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 2 3 4 5
```